# How can I iterate through a hashset within a hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to iterate through a hashmap which contains 8 entries. However one of these entries is a hashset 'balloon' with 2 objects within it. I want to add this to an array list so i can then iterate through it in a for loop/

First part of the code below works, I loop through the hashmap and look for the key I require which is 'balloon'. I need help to add the hashset to an array list.
I am getting a casting error when using Collectors.list and stream

```
 //This is the hashmap I am looping through to find the balloon key
    Map<String, Object> types = System.getPartyItems();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : types.entrySet()) {
        if (StringUtils.contains(entry.getKey().toString(), "balloon")) {

           //This is where I need to add the balloon hashset to a list to access the entries and values from within.
                List<PartyItem> myPartyList = new ArrayList<>();
                myPartyList.add (hash set of balloon objects)
```

Do i need to assign the hash set to a variable before i can set it to the list? Anything I've tried I am getting a casting error eg "class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head cannot be cast to class java.util.ArrayList"
Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: “This is where I need to loop through the balloon hashset” What balloon HashSet?  Nothing in the code in your question indicates a HashSet.  And why would you add objects to a PartyItem list when those objects are already in the list?

Comment: I have updated the code. I am retrieving the party items from another system, and wish to add the balloon items to a new list.  I have rephrased my question as i feel it would be easier adding the hashset of balloons (which is coming from another system) to an array list which i can then loop through. rather than looping through the hash set. But i cannot get the code to work to achieve this

Comment: "class java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head cannot be cast to class java.util.ArrayList" is the result of using streams.  We can’t help you with a problem we can’t see.  Show some actual code you tried, and the actual error produced by that code.  If you’ve tried multiple things, feel free to show each of those things in your question, each accompanied by the error it generated.

Answer (score 1):

Test if a value is a `Set` and if it is, add all items to your list.

```java
if (StringUtils.contains(entry.getKey().toString(), "balloon")
    && entry.getValue() instanceof Set) {
   myPartyList.addAll((Set)entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: it doesnt allow ,me to add set to the list. i am getting compilation errors

Comment: I'm just showing you the concept since the architecture you are using is not really obvious. More likely you need to make sure that types in your set are the same as types in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterating through entry just iterate through keys and when you find the balloon get the hashset to iterate through it.

```java
for(String key: types.keySet()){
    if(StringUtils.contains(key, "balloon")){
        for(Object object: types.get(key)){
            //do what you need with object
        }
    }
}
```

- After your edit it should be like this

```java
for(String key: types.keySet()){
    if(StringUtils.contains(key, "balloon")){
        ArrayList<Set<PartyItem>> myList = new ArrayList();
        myList.add(types.get(key));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate like this:

```
for(String key: Map.keySet()){
if(StringUtils.contains(key, "balloon")){
   Iterator<String> it = hashMap.get("balloon").iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
       // your code here
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Usually you structure your hashmap as <key, value> and you access your values via their corresponding keys. But they have to match exactly.
In your case your hashmap would look like this:

```
Map<String, Object> partyItems = myPartyList.getPartyItems();
// or maybe even
Map<String, PartyItem> partyItems = myPartyList.getPartyItems();
```

And getting the value is as easy as:

```
Object partyItem = partyItems.get("baloon");
```

If you are not sure if your paryItems contain a value for your key `baloon` you can check that first:

```
if (partyItems.contains("baloon")) {
    Object partyItem = partyItems.get("baloon");
}
```

If you are looking for a part of the key matching `baloon`:

```
List<PartyItem> myFilteredPartyItems = partyItems.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains("baloon"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
```

This is called stream oriented programming (take a look at the [Java Stream API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)), and if your run at least Java 8 you can use those.
And what it does, is turn the entries of the List to a stream, then remove everything which does not contain `baloon` in the key, and turn the resulting stream, which was not removed back to a list.

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-streams) you also find a very informative tutorial on how to use streams in Java.

Comment: check-then-fetch is asking for concurrency troubles, and it's slower (Just get, then check the result, or use `getOrDefault`). OP is not asking about how to query maps, they're asking about what to do with the thing that comes out of a map.